# Error in service: this."method" is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a class with a lot of methods to handle authentication in one of my angular 2 apps. One of the methods is used to handle errors thrown by the angular/http module. E.g. If a response is 401, the handler method would call a logout method in the same class, via this.logout(). But when I build the app and test it in a Browser I get a "this.logout() is not a function" as soon as a http request responds with a 401.

```
public handle(error: Response | any, caught: Observable<any>): Observable<ResponseError> {
    let errRes: ResponseError;

    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json();

        errRes = { message: body.message, statusCode: error.status };

        if (body.hasOwnProperty('authCheck')) {
            errRes.authCheck = body.authCheck;
        }

        if (_.inRange(errRes.statusCode, 401, 403)) {
            this.logout()
        }

    } else {
        const errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString()
        errRes = { message: errMsg }
    }

    return Observable.throw(errRes)
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `handle`?

Comment: Either `handle` is called in another context away of its class instance (the `this`), or you actually don't have this function in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with Typescript

In javascript (I'm unsure about typescript, but I can only assume), the `this` keyword doesn't actually persist the context in your callback.

You can get around this by naming something like `let _this = this;` in your services so that the `this` context is saved when the callback is called. Where the `_this` will refer to the context of your logout method i.e.

```
let _this = this;
_this.logout = function() { ... };
```

and then replace the `this.logout();` code with:

```
if(_.inRange(errRes.statusCode, 401, 403)) {
    _this.logout()
}
```

Comment: That code won't make a difference for the `this` in the callback though?!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. I was actually passing the method/function into the context on another func(handle). When I change it to:

```
func((error, caught) => {
    return handle(error, caught)
})
```

it works fine. Thanks for your thoughts.